# Probability of zero local maxima

Tags: probability, permutations

Given a permutation $f\in S_n$ acting $f:\{1,..,n\}\to\{1,..,n\}$, and a $k$ such that $1<k<n$, we call $k$ a local maxima if $f(k-1)<f(k)$ and $f(k+1)<f(k)$ .

If we pick a permutation of $S_n$ uniformly at random, what's the probability that there no local maxima?

Comment: @L.t. Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the element $n$ is the global maxima, and it is not a "local" maxima if and only if it is located at either end - location $1$ or location $n$.

And we must only allow at most $1$ local minima, otherwise a local maxima will exist in between two local minima. So that will also be the global minima - the element $1$.
A straight forward way (possibly have more simple combinatoric arguments)

Depends on the location of $1$, we will only allow the elements in between element $n$ and element $1$ to be strictly decreasing from $n$ to $1$ and the other elements strictly increasing away from $1$.

Suppose the element $n$ is located at the position $1$, and the element $1$ is located at position $i$, $i \in \{2, 3, \ldots n\}$.

We have $i-2$ elements between them, and $n-i$ elements outside of them. Once we partition the remaining $n-2$ elements (other than element $1$ and $n$) into two groups of these size, there will be only $1$ favorable permutation satisfy the above requirement. Therefore we only need to count the combination, which is

$$ \binom {n-2} {i-2}$$

Summing this from $i=2$ to $i=n$ to cater for all possible locations of the element $1$, and we multiply by $2$ by symmetry to cater for the case when the element $n$ is located at the position $n$, the total number of favorable permutations is

$$ 2 \sum_{i=2}^n \binom {n-2} {i-2} =
2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \binom {n-2} {i} = 2 \times 2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1} $$

Since each permutation is assumed to be equally-likely and there are totally $n!$ of possible permutation, the probability is

$$ \frac {2^{n-1}} {n!} $$

Comment: Quicker way to get to $2^{n-1}$: There are $n-1$ elements that are larger than $1$, and each of them is either before or after $1$, entirely independent of one another. This can be done in $2^{n-1}$ ways. There is not really anything special about the element $n$. Alternately, $n$ can be placed in either end. Then $n-1$ can be placed in either end of what's left. And so on, until the element $2$, which is the last element where you can choose.